# Select menu and input box together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, select, input

My PHP code generates options from MySQL db table for JQuery-ui autocomplete combobox http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox .
Code looks like that:

```
 <select id="combobox" name="company">
        <option value="">Select one...</option>
        <?php 
        $query=$db->query("SELECT id, company FROM main");
        while($row=$query->fetch_object())
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->company.'</option>';
            }
        ?>
    </select>
```

I wonder, is there any way to use Jquery-ui combobox as standard text input if there is no available option? I mean, if there's no option like user typed, I want to allow user to enter new data. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [this](http://coffeescripter.com/code/editable-select/) jQuery plugin for that.